# How much can you communicate with your familiar?

Tags: dnd-5e, familiars, animals

The *Find Familiar* spell states that:

> While your familiar is within 100 feet of you, you
>   can communicate with it telepathically.

and

> Your familiar acts independently of you, but it always
>   obeys your commands. In combat, it rolls its own
>   initiative and acts on its own turn. A familiar can’t
>   attack, but it can take other actions as normal.

None of the familiars in the *Find Familiar* list are capable of speaking, nor do they know languages. Nevertheless, they can understand your commands, and they can take actions like *Help* and *Search* which are largely language-driven actions.

Also, the description of the spell *Telepathy*
 reads:

> Until the spell ends, you and the target can
>   instantaneously share words, images, sounds, and
>   other sensory messages with one another through the
>   link, and the target recognizes you as the creature it
>   is communicating with. The spell enables a creature
>   with an Intelligence score of at least 1 to understand
>   the meaning of your words and take in the scope of any
>   sensory messages you send to it.

and *Speak with Animals* reads:

> You gain the ability to comprehend and verbally
>   communicate with beasts for the duration. The
>   knowledge and awareness of many beasts is limited
>   by their intelligence, but at minimum, beasts can
>   give you information about nearby locations and
>   monsters, including whatever they can perceive or have
>   perceived within the past day. You might be able to
>   persuade a beast to perform a small favor for you, at the
>   DM’s discretion.

To what extent can a simple animal familiar gained through *Find Familiar* understand and communicate/converse with you? Does *Find Familiar* intrinsically include the capabilities under *Telepathy* and *Speak with Animals* as you interact with your familiar?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Your familiar understands you perfectly.

You've already quoted nearly all relevant text in your answer. Telepathy (within range) communicates without necessarily using words, but the target (with int >= 1) understands perfectly.

I think your confusion comes from when you state

> simple animal familiar gained

There is simply no such thing. From the spell description:

> You gain the service of a familiar, a *spirit* that takes an animal form

and thus it's impossible for it to actually be a simple animal.

Comment: Thank you!
The reason I mentioned "simple animal" was to differentiate from the creatures that warlocks can get.

Comment: I can see now what you were going for, but I still think it's important to emphasize the inherent difference there. The standard spirit familiars are much more closely related to the Warlock's imp/pseudodragon/quasit/sprite than the beasts they resemble.