# Can a wizard telepathically speak with & control their familiar whilst incapacitated yet conscious?

Tags: dnd-5e, familiars

A wizard (with a familiar) is possessed by a *ghost*. Can this *incapacitated* yet conscious-observing wizard still speak telepathically to their familiar, one that is within 100'?

Comment: Related (dupe?): [Can a wizard under the effects of Feign Death issue telepathic commands to their familiar?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/169335/52137)

Comment: Not sure whether it'l make a difference, but are you asking about a *find familiar* familiar or a voluntary familiar?

Comment: It seems like both questions are can you control a familiar when incapacitated, but please let us know if you don't agree!

Comment: This answer = excellent: 'yes - control a familiar whilst incapacitated.'' Do whatever you like with my question! This query was neither 'creative' nor 'compelling'  - just necessary to get all the parts together. My thanks to all.